# where to find the CSS variable definition in asp.net website

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying find where "menu" is defined in my asp.net website for

```
background-color: menu;
```

in my `menu.css.aspx` file. I am fairly new to this notation. Please suggest me a way to find it.

Comment: `menu` is not a valid value for `background-color` in CSS.

Comment: `menu.css.aspx`? Is this a stylesheet or a ASP web form?

Comment: well I don't think it should have an `.aspx` extension then. It should be `menu.css`. The only way I know of setting variables in CSS is to use LESS, but those variables begin with an `@` sign. Do a `ctrl+f` and do a search for it in the project if you are just trying to find it.